# VB6 to VB.net about SHBrowseForFolder

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have a problem between convert vb6 to vb.net

I can't use this line because BrowseCallbackProc is fuction that have parameter

```
.lpfn = pfncGetProcAddress(AddressOf BrowseCallbackProc)
```

And this is function

```
Private Function BrowseCallbackProc(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal uMsg As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer, ByVal lpData() As Byte) As Integer
```

What I should do

Comment: So use a method with the correct signature. If the callback is not supposed to return anything, as you would expect would be the case, then use a `Sub` rather than a `Function`.  Also, declare the method with whatever parameters the unmanaged signature dictates.  If parameters are expected, declare them.  If not, don't.

Comment: I've only seen this used when a dialog allowing the user to select a folder is being shown. If this is what you're trying to convert then you don't want to convert it. You want to replace it with native .NET code. This functionality is built into the FolderBrowserDialog component, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-choose-folders-with-the-windows-forms-folderbrowserdialog-component

Comment: If BrowseCallbackProc is an already-existing procedure which you can't change, then you should write a wrapper following @jmcilhinney 's suggestions which calls it internally.